# Which logs should I pay attention to?

Tags: administration

There are many logs in `/var/log/`  For a standard home installation, which ones should I be checking regularly?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Each log serves it's own purpose. It really depends on what you're trying to check for. Some common ones are outlined below:

- `/var/log/auth.log` - Information pertaining to authentication - including sudo/su activity
- `/var/log/boot.log` - All information during the booting process
- `/var/log/crond.log` - Information from cron daemon
- `/var/log/messages` - Typical dumping point for messages not regarding the system
- `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` - Logged during the Power management suspend function
- `/var/log/user.log` - Information from all userlevels
- `/var/log/syslog` - This organizes output from different softwares and is a "general log"
- `/var/log/kern.log` - Information being logged from the kernel

There are additional logs - like the apache2 folder, mysql.log/mysql.err, and others. These are all software specific - if you don't have apache2 installed, you won't have the log files for it. The only time you would want to check logs is when an issue arises - most of the time though it'll be okay to let them sit in the dark.

Comment: I have three logfiles (kern,messages and syslog) totally spammed by crazy "NVRM: os_raise_smp_barrier(), invalid context!" message. So I dont check it anymore....

Comment: `egrep -v 'os_raise_smp_barrier' /var/log/{kern.log,messages,syslog} | less`  

And, track down that message - it's symptomatic of some problem that you should fix.

Comment: You could ask `rsyslogd` which files it logs to: `cat /etc/rsyslog.d/* | egrep -v '^#|^$'  | egrep -o '/[^ ]+'` on your system.

Answer (score 14):

I would argue that for a standard home installation, there is no need for you to be checking any logs regularly. Though they may be helpful in diagnosing a problem or filing a bug report.

Comment: I concur: unless you're seriously concerned about security auditing - which is unlikely to be particularly useful for your home PC - the logs are there for figuring out what's gone wrong after something's gone wrong :)

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can just use the command "dmesg" to see the kernel messages (same as /var/log/kern.log) 
This usually tells me quickly what is (if anything) going wrong with the system

Answer (score 2):

A trick that I find useful is:

```
touch /tmp/now  

<...make the problem happen...>  

sudo find /var/log -type f -newer /tmp/now | xargs sudo less
```

That shows me every file in and under `/var/log` that has had something written to it since the `touch /tmp/now` command.