# Tutorial on making use of logs

Tags: log, administration

I know I can find logs in `/var/log/`, they contain powerful information, but I don't really use them often (on desktop or server).

Is there any good guide to learn how to make use of system logs on Ubuntu? Top things an user/basic admin needs to know?

E.g.

- check this log weekly
- keep this file clean
- set up log notification this way
- when somethings wired happened, start here
- use this tool to simplify your life
- common command line usages
- common uses of `grep` searching the logs

or any other tips to new users coming from Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st have a look at the answer by MaroCeppi here: [Which logs should I pay attention to?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5868/which-logs-should-i-pay-attention-to) It explains what some of the more common logs are used for. There is one more log named `.xsession-errors` in your home dir (and this records your login and has amongst others errors on loading indicators and laucher items), and often grows VERY large, especially if you never log out.

In general there is no need to check logs weekly. Security might be an exception but if that's the case your system probably is hosting a server (Apache for instance) and then it is more for seeing irregular access instead of errors. 
I tend to not look at them unless something is really broken.

Specifically targeting your questions:

> use this tool to simplify your life

`log file viewer` is a good place to start:

[image: im1]

> set up log notification this way and when somethings wired happened, start here

It is a bit hard to answer this but I always start with `dmesg` or with the log related to the problem (no need to look in .xsession-errors when you get an error during booting ;) )

> common command line usages and common uses of grep searching the logs

Commands that are rather useful:

`cat` will list the whole file.

`grep` will filter commands.

`tail -f` will keep a file active and you will see new notices show up in it when they happen. Rather helpful when tracking down what action you do results in a problem.
(`tail -100` will show the last 100 lines)

`wc -l` to count how many times some search happend.

`more` and `less` show the file too.

One example of this:

How many times did someone try to login on 'our' apacher server using IP address 111.111.111.111: `grep "GET /login.js" /var/log/httpd/access.log | grep  111.111.111.111 | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

Just after an "event" that you need to investigate, do a `ls -rlt /var/log` to get a reversed, time-ordered (by modification time) list of log files (most recently modified file last) to look at.