# Is it necessary to monitor cron/anacron?

Tags: 11.10, cron

I use Ubuntu at home for my personal matters, not as a "server". I shut down my computer two or three times a day and there aren't any fixed usage times. I understand that there are automated tasks set to run at particular times of the day, week or month and that `cron` and `anacron` are involved. Apart from not having a regular usage schedule, I'm also *blessed* with an imperfect internet connection. How can I know whether the various tasks, such as maintenance or updating Ubuntu's databases, are being satisfactorily completed? I came across [Which logs should I pay attention to?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5868/which-logs-should-i-pay-attention-to) which referred to `/var/log/crond.log` but I don't have such a log nor even a log with "anacron" in the name.

I keep up with all software updates by running `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` more than once a day and accept all updates. I don't have any *performance* issues that I know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing that, then most of the relevant tasks are done. You could get Log Viewer 2.32.0 (current) to view all the logs on the PC. It is in the software manager.

[image]

The answer to the question is NO. You DON'T have to monitor those things. It's nice to know where to find them and IF you needed to examine them for whatever reason.