# Log user activity for the last 24 hours by terminal

Tags: command-line, monitoring

How can I log the activity of users for the last 24 hours by terminal in a system? Which command will give me this information?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which logs should I pay attention to?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5868/which-logs-should-i-pay-attention-to)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `~/.bash_history` will show the commands that was used by a user.
- Install **acct** : `sudo apt-get install acct` in addition to login/logout. It provides  logs of every single command run by every single user. Below mentioned commands are the features of acct

  - `ac`      print statistics about connect time
  - `accton`      turns accounting on or off
  - `last`        list last logins of users and terms
  - `lastcomm`        list last commands executed
  - `sa`      print accounting statistics
  - `dump-acct`      print accounting file in human-readable form

Answer (score 7):

The "last" command is designed to give you this information.

Example:

```
laptop:~% last
userx pts/0        :0.0             Mon Sep  3 11:31   still logged in   
userx pts/0        :0.0             Mon Sep  3 11:30 - 11:30  (00:00)    
userx pts/0        :0.0             Mon Sep  3 11:30 - 11:30  (00:00)    
userx pts/4        :0.0             Mon Sep  3 11:25   still logged in   
userx pts/2        :0.0             Mon Sep  3 11:23 - 11:28  (00:05)    
userx pts/2        :0.0             Mon Sep  3 11:20 - 11:20  (00:00)    
root  pts/1        :0.0             Mon Sep  3 11:19 - 11:28  (00:09)    
root  pts/1        :0.0             Mon Sep  3 11:19 - 11:19  (00:00)    
userx pts/0        :0.0             Mon Sep  3 11:10 - 11:12  (00:01)    
root  pts/1        :0.0             Mon Sep  3 11:05 - 11:10  (00:04)    
userx pts/3        :0.0             Mon Sep  3 10:18   still logged in   

wtmp begins Mon Sep  3 10:18:35 2012
```

However as far as I know, there is no option to restrict the lookup to the last 24 hours.

Comment: The latest output of `last` is from 4 days ago. Doesn't make any sense :/

Answer (score 0):

1. who

The who command Shows who is currently logged in to the system and information such as the time of the last login. You can use options such as
-H (display column headings)
-r (current runlevel)
-a (display information provided by most options).

2. w

The ‘w‘ command Displays information about the users currently on the machine and their processes. The first line includes information on the current time, how long the system has been running, how many users are currently logged on, and the system load averages for the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes.

3. last

The last command displays a list of users who logged in and out since the /var/log/wtmp file was created. The last command searches back through the /var/log/wtmp file (or the file designated by the -f option) and displays a list of all users who have logged in (and out) since the file was created. You can specify names of users and TTY’s to show only information for those entries.

4. lastlog

The lastlog command formats and prints the contents of the last login log file (/var/log/lastlog). The login name, port, and last login time are displayed.

Entering the command without options displays the entries sorted by numerical ID. You can use options such as -u login_name (display information for designated user only) and -h (display a one-line help message). If a user has never logged in, the message **Never logged in** is displayed in place of the port and time. For example, entering lastlog returns information similar to the following: