# How to access user's activity log

Tags: users, log

How can I get the log that says programs which are opened by user with time stamp . I would like to develop a system to monitor and give suggestions using this user activity log.

Comment: Have a look at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5868/which-logs-should-i-pay-attention-to and http://askubuntu.com/questions/183524/log-user-activity-for-the-last-24-hours-by-terminal

Comment: i want to get  the  Ubuntu  PC user log activity .

Comment: read the above links and also see if this is enough for you: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/utils/activity-log-manager