# Laptop suddenly rebooted

Tags: 12.04, reboot

My laptop has rebooted suddenly without any warnings, but it has closed all programms, and killed all processes as if it was me who send it in reboot.
The question is - where in logs can I see what caused the reboot?

Comment: Possibly relavent: http://askubuntu.com/q/5868/101890

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it reboots automaticlly because of updates. It happened to me and later I found out it was because of updates.

To have a look at logs, look at `/var/log`.

To see the boot log, go to `/var/log/boot.log`.

If you need any more log locations, go [here to find them](https://askubuntu.com/a/5874/101890).

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Surely it should request to reboot before doing so automatically, mine always does.

Comment: @handuel - Mine does to. But I kept on ignoring it, so it must of rebooted. But still, who knows?

Comment: Maybe there's some kind of timeout. Just seems odd.

Comment: @handuel - Maybe. Maybe.

Comment: You know, guys, I've compared data in kern.log and syslog and found out time when it rebooted(16:08. Segfault of dconf 16:08. Kernel logging stopped), and the previous "event" before system stopped logging is removing of an SD card. It this ever possible, can (unapropriate) removind of an SD card cause reboot?

Comment: Sometimes. It depends on your SD card. Some are set to remove without warning safely, some aren't. And if it isn't set to remove without warning, the computer could cause a sudden shutdown.