# My laptop shuts down while playing Hollow Knight

Tags: nvidia, shutdown, steam

I downloaded Hollow Knight from Steam and at first everything was OK, but today after playing for some minutes, it shuts down. I don't even know where to begin diagnosing the problem. My laptop is Acer Aspire V17 Nitro, with Nvidia 960M 4GB, and have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on it. I'm playing it on my TV by using it as a second monitor. It was fine and played nice before, but this problem started today. I appreciate any help

PS.  If it's any help, it also shuts down hard shortly after I connect a USB type-C hub to it, even without connecting any devices. I'm suspecting some power settings probably at the kernel aren't optimized somehow.

Comment: Does it happen repeatedly?

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: @user3430996 Yes.I tried playing without using the TV, it lasted longer but it still shut down. I'll try later with the Intel integrated graphics and see how it goes.

Comment: @user535733 How do I extract logs?

Comment: [Locating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186276) and [reading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5868) logs has been asked and answered already.

Comment: @user3430996 It works fine with the Intel integrated graphics. And unlike when using nvidia it was quiet.

Comment: @user535733 There are a lot of them. Which log do you need specifically?

Comment: Read the logs yourself, then you decide which say something useful.

Comment: It seems due to overheating. The fan gets a bit loud and the laptop does heat up.